# mdm.Browser onDocumentComplete Event not firing in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, flex3, mdm-zinc, zinc-4

In my MAC based application I have loaded a client login URL into the mdm browser instance.The browser instance is not firing the onDocumentComplete event on MAC 10.6 and above.

Following are the variants I tried to achieve the same:

```
_myBrowser = new mdm.Browser("c", "c", "50%", "50%", "http://www.multidmedia.com", true);

Alternative 1:

_myBrowser.onDocumentComplete = function(event:mdm.Event):void {
  mdm.Dialogs.prompt("calling in document complete");
  alert.show("calling in document complete");
}

Alternate 2:

_myBrowser.onDocumentComplete = function(myObject)
{
   alert.show("calling in document complete");
   //message = myObject.url + " loaded successfully!");
}

Alternate 3:

_myBrowser.addEventListener("onDocumenteComplete", onDocumenteCompleteHandler);

function onDocumenteCompleteHandler(event:mdm.Event):void
{
   mdm.Dialogs.prompt("calling in document complete");
   var url:String = event.data.result;
};
```

Unfortunately, None of the above mentioned alternatives worked. This is working as expected in Windows OS.

I have used MDM 4.0.14. What can be the issue?